# How threads know about the address of a shared variable

Tags: c, multithreading

I am new to multi-threading in C and was wondering how a shared (non-global and non-static) variable declared in a function can be shared among threads. I know that we can declare both simple variables like

```
int a;
```

or dynamic ones like

```
a = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

for sharing data.But, what it is not clear for me is that how compiler acts in each case?

1) Does it give the address of variable created inside the stack of its thread to other threads or what?

2) How about the dynamically allocated variable? Is its pointer broadcast? Or the pointer is kept somewhere in .DATA or .BSS??

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not a c-proficient person, but I thought that Within a single OS process, all threads share the same memory map.  Memory allocated on one thread is not in a different place or managed in a different way, from memory allocated on any other thread, right?  The only distinction I was aware of that needs to be made is for Single Threaded Apartments (STAs), where some restrictions are necessary to control what functions are allowed to manipulate resources (windows, graphics objects, etc.) created on one thread from those on another...

Comment: Each thread has its own stack but the heap is shared.

Comment: But isn't the stack for each thread still part of the same memory map issued by the OS to the process that all threads reside within ?  i.e., if one thread has the virtual address of a variable from another thread, it does not need to "thunk" out to the OS to get the actual physical address to access it.

Comment: Threads have their own stack to allow creation and release of stack frames for functions that have been called on a thread of execution, so that the thread knows where to return to when a function executing on a thread finishes processing... not to control access to memory...

Comment: Yes, exactly. But as you know accessing the variables inside another thread's stack requires either accessing that thread's stack pointer or having the absolute address of that variable inside the stack.

Comment: The address of a shared variable is just an address. For other threads to access it, you'll need to pass them that address. While each thread has its own stack, all threads can see all stacks, provided they have an address to it. Which means that if you never take the address of a stack-based object (where object=region of storage), you don't have to worry about it being accessed from other threads.

Comment: @ninjalj: Awesome! This is what I myself think it should be like.

Comment: right, this is a non-issue... If you pass a variable "from one thread" to a function executing in a different thread, the other thread does not know, or care, what thread the variable was created on... It just accesses the memory address, period.  There is no need to acsess a threads' "stack pointer", or know anything sabout the variables physical (is that what you meant by absolute?>) address.  The virtual address of the variable is passed in the functions parameter list, and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

How you declare your variable and how it's treated in a thread isn't something the compiler cares about. It's your job to decide how you'll allocate it.

For example, if you've got an `int a` allocated on the stack then you need to ensure that the variable will survive the lifetime of any threads that access it. This will typically mean joining any threads before your variable goes out of scope.

If you allocate the variable on the heap then your threads can access the variable without having to worry about the memory going out of scope. However, you will need to decide how you are going to free up the memory allocated by `malloc`. One thread will need to be the "owner" of the memory and call `free` against it, otherwise you will have a memory leak.

To pass the pointer to the threads will vary depending on which platform and threading library you use. However, they all allow you to pass some sort of parameter, typically a `void*` For example, the 4th parameter to [pthread_create](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) allows you to pass a pointer into your thread function.

Comment: Thanks. But, I already know what happens in high level language. What I am looking for is how the shared (non-static and non-global) variable's location is known by other threads.

Comment: @user3684042 - fair enough. I've added some more info to the answer.